# jQuery tooltip clickable?

Tags: jquery, tooltip, jquery-tooltip

I'm using this tooltip plugin: http://bassistance.de/jquery-plugins/jquery-plugin-tooltip/

Is there any way I can make the tooltip clickable? I don't want the tooltip to disappear when I try to mouse-over it.

If not, what other jQuery plugin do you recommend that will allow clickable tooltips? One feature I NEED is the ability to specify custom content for the tooltip, content which is not associated with any other HTML element in the page.

Thanks!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its easier to have a `div` to slide up and use the same.

Thanks
Jean

Answer (score 2):

I prepared an example with clickable tooltips on jsfiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/PEH7t/12/